# "This site can't be reached" error while loading my WordPress site locally

Tags: wordpress

Tried every fix I could find on Youtube, no luck.

This is what it is showing:

[image: Screenshot of the website throwing a "This site can't be reached" error]

Please give me a solution to this problem. It's being irritating from last 2 days.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure port 8082 isn’t being blocked by your firewall